# Play audio when game object is in the process of being null?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to play an audio for when the item is retrieved. Once the item is no longer in the scene there is no audio to derive from. Is there any way I can play this once the object is no longer available? I've tried `PlayOneShot` but that gave me errors in the console. I've only really used audio to attach on gameobjects.

```
public Item item; 

public GameObject Item;

//public AudioSource source;

public Transform targetItem;
public string achievmentName;



//public int scoreValue = 10;
int waterMask;

public float maxCastDist = 1000f;
public float itemDist = 1f;
//public float itemDist = 1f;
//public float enemyDist = 1f;

public bool hitObject;


void Awake ()
{

    waterMask = LayerMask.GetMask ("Water"); // will only cast in water

}

void Start()
{
    //source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void Update ()
{
    //if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
    if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject ()) {
        return;

    } else {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            RaycastHit hit;

            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, maxCastDist, waterMask))
            if (hit.collider != null) {

                //Destroy (GameObject.FindWithTag ("Float"));
                float dist = Vector3.Distance (hit.point, targetItem.position);
                Debug.Log (dist);



                //Instantiate (Float, hit.point, Quaternion.identity);
                if (dist < itemDist) {

                    itemAdd(); // Will "retrieved" Item
                } 

            }
        }
    }
}



void itemAdd ()
{
    //Destroy (GameObject.FindWithTag ("Item"));
    Item = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Item");
    Item.SetActive(false);

    bool wasPickedUp = Inventory.instance.Add (item);

    if (wasPickedUp)

    print ("You Caught The" + item.name );
    AchievementManager.Instance.EarnAchievment (achievmentName);
    //ScoreManager.score += scoreValue;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you remove all of the unnecessary code from your question?  for example the commented out if statements, instantiates, Destroys, and commented out variables you are not using...  Also, please give us an idea how you are doing it?  if there is no audio to derive from then how are we suppose to know how to fix it and how are you using `PlayOneShot` it isn't anywhere in your code.  Your only audiosource is commented out, and doesn't appear to be used anywhere.  From what I am seeing with what you posted, you aren't doing anything with audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sound manager, you can call to play a sound before destroy your gameobject and it will be played by the manager and not the gameobject you are destroying.

```
SoundManager.instance.PlaySingle(myClip);
Destroy(this.gameObject);
```

SoundManager will be a class with a AudioSource and you will be able to play sonds from it. [Like this one](https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-roguelike-tutorial/audio-and-sound-manager)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

    public class SoundManager : MonoBehaviour 
    {
        public AudioSource efxSource;                   //Drag a reference to the audio source which will play the sound effects.
        public AudioSource musicSource;                 //Drag a reference to the audio source which will play the music.
        public static SoundManager instance = null;     //Allows other scripts to call functions from SoundManager.             
        public float lowPitchRange = .95f;              //The lowest a sound effect will be randomly pitched.
        public float highPitchRange = 1.05f;            //The highest a sound effect will be randomly pitched.


        void Awake ()
        {
            //Check if there is already an instance of SoundManager
            if (instance == null)
                //if not, set it to this.
                instance = this;
            //If instance already exists:
            else if (instance != this)
                //Destroy this, this enforces our singleton pattern so there can only be one instance of SoundManager.
                Destroy (gameObject);

            //Set SoundManager to DontDestroyOnLoad so that it won't be destroyed when reloading our scene.
            DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
        }


        //Used to play single sound clips.
        public void PlaySingle(AudioClip clip)
        {
            //Set the clip of our efxSource audio source to the clip passed in as a parameter.
            efxSource.clip = clip;

            //Play the clip.
            efxSource.Play ();
        }


        //RandomizeSfx chooses randomly between various audio clips and slightly changes their pitch.
        public void RandomizeSfx (params AudioClip[] clips)
        {
            //Generate a random number between 0 and the length of our array of clips passed in.
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, clips.Length);

            //Choose a random pitch to play back our clip at between our high and low pitch ranges.
            float randomPitch = Random.Range(lowPitchRange, highPitchRange);

            //Set the pitch of the audio source to the randomly chosen pitch.
            efxSource.pitch = randomPitch;

            //Set the clip to the clip at our randomly chosen index.
            efxSource.clip = clips[randomIndex];

            //Play the clip.
            efxSource.Play();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you I really needed an example to go by!